# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, helper

I got below link to solve problem related to class and instance method.
http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/09/20/concerning-yourself-with-active-support-concern/

```
module NotificationsHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def my_class_method
      # ...
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def my_instance_method
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

But I am getting **uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Concern** error. I am using `Rails 2.3.5` and `Ruby 1.9.2p180`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This module is only available in Rails 3 onwards